# jQuery AJAX Success callback

Tags: jquery, ajax, knockout.js, jquery-callback

I'm using knockoutjs and have multiple ajax calls in my project in different script files.
I want to streamline the calls into one utility script and I have implemented the following:

Script File A:

```
function ABC(){
function myCallbackFunction(result){
///
}
$Callbacks.add(myCallbackFunction);

var UtilityObj = new ClsUtility();
UtilityObj .GetData(myJSONObj);
}

Script File B:
function ClsUtility(){
function GetData(myJSONObj){
$.ajax(
////
success: $.Callbacks.fire(result);
);

}
}
```

The callback function is not getting called.
Help me find out the solution.

Thanks,
Rahul Adwani

Comment: can you share a bit more code, a working fiddle will be appreciated

Comment: `success: $.Callbacks.fire(result);` it looks like you are **calling** the callbacks at this point instead of **assigning** one, unless `.fire` really returns a function.

Comment: I changed the code to look like:
success: function (result) {
$.Callbacks.fire(result);
}
still the callback function is not getting executed.

Answer (score 0):

You may remove parenthesis like :

```
success: $.Callbacks.fire
```

that's equivalent to :

```
success: function(result){
    $.Callbacks.fire(result);
}
```

but you can't set a pointer function with parenthesis

Comment: It might not be equivalent. In the first case `this` probably refers to `window` inside `.fire`, in the second one it will refer to `$.Callbacks`. Depending how the code is structured, this can be a problem or not.